# How to change the localhost with particular domain name?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am checking the links of any domain name whether the links are working or not .but as i am debugging from the localhost i can't particular domain name eg `localhost:xyz/preferences?hl=en` instead of this I want (http://google.co.in/preferences?hl=en) so can we do by replace string

```
var linkWithLocalHost = "http://localhos:234/foo"; 

var result = // ??? some code that manipulates linkWithLocalHost 
// expecting "http://google.co.il/foo" as result
```

Comment: Can you instead of the random code you have post code with string constants and comment on desired output (i.e. `var s = "http://example.com/foo";` , expecting `"http://localhost:333/foo"` as result)

Comment: no i dont have like that i first render the page and then  find hyper link and that is store in var links

Comment: I see. Since you can't simplify your sample code to show input and desired output I'm afraid I can't help. Good luck.

Comment: Try a Regex string replace, search for an example at the [Regular Expression Library](http://regexlib.com)

Comment: I've took liberty to change your sample to my understanding of your requirements, feel free to revert the edit.

Answer (score 0):

One more random guess (as I'm likely oversimplifying the requirements).

To manipulate Url please use corresponding classes `Uri` and `UriBuilder`:

```
var linkWithLocalHost = "http://localhos:234/foo"; 
// expecting "http://google.co.il/foo" as result

var builder  = new UriBuilder(linkWithLocalHost);
builder.Host = "google.co.il";
builder.Port = 80;
var result = builder.Uri.ToString();
```

Answer to the question in the title is:

- use hosts file (if using IIS as server)
- use Fiddler to remap domain names (for either VS web server or IIS or any other server)

Comment: @hitarth probably my answer is not related to your question... also I'm sort of lost on what you want to achieve - see comment to question.

Comment: yes bro..here is question to you..i have linkcher project in that i find all broken links ,but when i run the project the links which are throwing the webrequest from my local host whether the link is working or not that comes in "http://localhost:333/foo" like so that the errors generates "  Invalid Link : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. " so i want that link instead of local host  if i have find links for google.co.in then it would have "http://google.co.in/...." so if we can replace that it can be done

Answer (score 0):

You can use C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file. In the file there are instructions that show how to use it.

For example I appended a new line to this file which is:

```
127.0.0.1 mywebsite # for stackoverflow question
```

Now when I write `http://mywebsite/` to my browser's address bar, I see the page that normally I would see when I write `http://localhost/`.